# How to get a list of appendices using overleaf?

Tags: appendices, appendix

I need help with the appendix on Overleaf; I am using [Thesis Template][1]
i want to list the appendices using \listofappendices  the appandix file contain a pdf file
i have tried other answers this one worked for me

```
\documentclass[twoside]{utmthesis}
%According to the new manual, should not mixed single-side with two-side printing
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url} 
%\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\dbm{\decibel{}m}
\DeclareSIUnit\mvrms{\milli\volt{}_{RMS}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%adding appendix 
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
%ending appendix
%%% You MUST load the natbib package if you want to use author-date bibliography style. Also remember to change the bibliography style at the bottom of the .tex file.
% Comment natbib for citation by number
\usepackage{natbib}
\let\cite\citep
%adding stack exchange figure adjusmen%
\newcommand*{\MyIncludeGraphics}[2][]{%
\begin{adjustbox}{max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}}
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
\end{adjustbox}
}
%ending 
%This is to make sure vertical spacing non-stretchable
\raggedbottom






\begin{appendices}

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{figs/appendix.pdf}
\end{appendices}
```

but the appandix heading is not showing up in the \listofappendices.

I am new to latex so if you can help me  I really appreciate it
here the .cls file

````
 [P18] Appendices
% ----------------------------------------
% Copied from book.cls:
% \appendix  - to indicate the start of appendix section
  \renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{A\arabic{chapter}}
  \@appendixtrue
  \settocdepth{chapter}
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}
  \phantomsection
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\@twolinespacing}}
  %\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\noindent\MakeUppercase{\bf\appendicesname}}
  %\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{\@twolinespacing}}%
}
```
```
 [P15] List of Appendices
% ----------------------------------------
\newcommand{\listofappendices}{
  \clearpage
  \section*{\centering\listappendixname}
  \phantomsection 
  \label{pre:listofappendices}
  \vspace{23pt}
  \setstretch{1.435} 
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace{\toc@tab@a}\MakeUppercase{\listappendixname}} 
  \@showpagenumber

  \begingroup
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \begin{center}
      \bfseries\MakeUppercase{%
        \appendixnum@colname\hfill%
        \title@colname\hfill\hspace{2.5em}%
        \page@colname}
      \linebreak
    \end{center}  
  \endgroup
  \setstretch{1.435}
  \vspace{-17pt}
  \@starttoc{loapp}
}


```


  


  [1]: http://%20https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/universiti-teknologi-malaysia-thesis-template/vhhykxgsxcym
````

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in this template as

```
\begin{appendices}

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{figs/appendix.pdf}
\end{appendices}
```

For an appendix you use

```
\appendix
```

(only once -- and it is already in the template.

And then for each appendix:

```
\chapter{Title of appendix}
Contents of appendix.
```

Now your problem is caused because the template uses `listofpublications` wrong.

Instead of

```
\listofpublications

 Paper 1
 Paper 2
```

it should use

```
\begin{listofpublications}
 Paper 1
 Paper 2
\end{listofpublications}
```

If you make this change, the appendix will appear in the list of appendices.
(If the appendices are before the list of publications as in the original template, this error will not show, but it is still an error.

Comment: Thank you for the comment; in my .tex file, I have deleted the list of publications because it is not required for the FYP project report, but still the issue exists.

Comment: The issue is that I would like to include survey questionnaire PDF documents that I used in my study. At the moment, I can see the appandix title  at the end of the document but not in the list of appandicies

Comment: i have fixed it by adding at the end of the appandix \endmatter now i want to add the pdf document what command should i write  this one did not work %\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{figs/appendix.pdf}

Comment: Pieter I would like to  add the pdf document now what command should i use thanks.

Comment: First, in the beginning of the document, add a line `\usepackage{pdfpages}`
and then, where you want the pages included,
add the line above (without the % of course).